Linq - C# : Create Concatenated Lists and Sub-Lists
I have the following table :



Country
Team
Player




England
MU
1


England
MU
2


England
MU
3


England
LIV
4


England
LIV
5


Spain
RM
6


Spain
RM
7


Spain
BAR
8


Spain
BAR
9


Spain
BAR
10



And i want to get this output :



Country
Team & Player




England
MU(1,2,3) - LIV(4,5)


Spain
RM(6,7) - BAR(8,9,10)



I tried for several times till i developed following linq query but couldn't adjust it
to give the required output :
var output= _model.GroupBy(x => new { x.Country })
            .Select(y =>
            {   
              var distinctTeam = y.Where(z => (z.Player !=  null)).Select(z => z.Team);
              return new
                {   
                   Country = y.Key.Country,
                   Team&Player= string.Join(" - ", distinctTeam.Select(z => $"{z} 
                          ({y.Where(c => c.Team == z && ((c.Team != 
                           null))).SelectMany(x=> string.Join(" , 
                           ",xPlayer)))})").Distinct())
                 };
              }).ToList();

Your support is highly appreciated.

For starters, Team&Player isn't a valid property name. That ampersand will cause an error. Second, you're going to want a nested GroupBy() for teams, e.g.:
var output = _model
  .GroupBy(g => g.Country)
  .Select(c => new {
    Country = c.Key,
    TeamAndPlayer = string.Join(" - ", c
      .GroupBy(c => c.Team)
      .Select(t => $"{t.Key}({string.Join(",", t.Select(p => p.Player))})")
    )         
  });


Perfect, worked like charm. Thanks
